# Susy "static" container style

Tags: css, static, susy-compass

I know I can assign a global container-style value. But what I would like to know is if I can assign a static value for a given element.

For example:

```
.wrapper{
    @ include span-columns (10 static);
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the [Susy One docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/susyone/#span-columns) - there is a `$style` argument, so you would use `span-columns(10, $style: static)`.

With Susy 2.0, you could use the shorter `span(10 static)`.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, yes. [See this multiple containers demo](https://gist.github.com/ericam/3077992). I think the container style should also be changeable in this way.